# I like to order my .tex documents visually by inserting blank lines. How to tell Latex to not put a new line there, but only with \\?

Tags: formatting

When editing my documents in Texstudio I like to visually have some parts separated. Usually I would leave some blank lines in the .tex file. But Latex translates this into a linebreak/new line.
Is there a possibility to stop it from doing that and only have linebreaks when putting a `\\` ?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, and you should  use  \\ exceptionally (it is used for multiline equations environments, tabulars, &c.). To order visually your source-code, why don't you insert lines containing only the `comment` sign `%`?

Comment: Oh that's an amazing idea! I never thought about that! If you post the comment as an answer I can mark it as 'approved'.
Why shouldn't I use \\ so much? I use it for example after finishing a paragraph. Isn't it the same as two blank lines?

Comment: _never_ use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph! It generates a warning about underfull hbox badness 10000 (infinitely bad) and produces a spurious white line that is not vertical space but an empty line of text that is not discarded at a page break.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I never thought much about that error. So instead I should just use two blank lines?

Comment: one blank line (two returns) is an end of paragraph, `\\ ` is for the rare case you want to have a line break (leaving a short line) within a paragraph.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I thought it would be the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't: blank lines are used by TeX-the-program to indicate a new paragraph (the basic unit for text formatting), and you should use `\\` exceptionally (it is used for multiline equations environments, tabulars, &c.).

To order visually your source-code, why don't you insert lines containing only the `comment` sign `%`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to use empty comments instead of blank linkes:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
%
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
%
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
%
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```